# Soundcloud API /resolve method 404 error

Tags: javascript, json, api, authorization, soundcloud

Simple dimple one here- trying to use Soundcloud's `resolve` method to retrieve a JSON feed of track data for a **private set**.

---

http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=http://soundcloud.com/myUser/private-set

`resolve` returns a `401` unauthorized error, as it should

http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=http://soundcloud.com/myUser/private-set&client_id=myClientID

`resolve` returns a '404' not found error. it should be 301 redirecting to the authorized JSON feed for the track, such as http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/49931.json in the doc's example

---

- I've [created an App](http://soundcloud.com/you/apps/new)
- I'm using the App's Client ID
- I've enabled App access in the Set's edit menu
- I'm formatting it as per the [API docs](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve)

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is the set you're trying to access private?

Comment: So I think what's happening is you're getting a 404 because the set isn't public. Can you make the set public and test again?

Comment: @bbone, no it has to remain private. Finding it hard to believe that I can't access a private set with combination of ClientID and SecretKey or something

Answer (score 2):

So after some testing I've confirmed that the issue is related to the fact that you're trying to request a private set. Because the set is private, you would need to first go through SoundCloud's [OAuth 2 authentication](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#authentication) process before being able to access the set.

Comment: That's really shocking. the OAuth method is really for users to connect a service to their account. In this case, I'm simply playing back a private set in a custom player. Thanks for digging into this. I'm interested to see what Soundcloud Dev says.

Comment: No problem. Think of it this way -- in order to view private playlist SoundCloud needs to know if you have permission to view that playlist. Without authentication the api has no way of knowing who's making the request and subsequently whether or not that request has permission to access the information being requested. The client id is not enough to ensure a secure request because it's publicly available in the url meaning anyone could grab it and use it to obtain private information about the account associated with the client id.

Let me know what you hear back.

Answer (score 1):

Try resolving the set url with the url found in the share dialog of your set. This url contains a secret token that can be used to access a private set without logging in.

Not sure how far this'll get you if the tracks in the set are also private, though. And like bbone mentioned, you'll be exposing this secret token, which may or may not be a problem.